# Cannot stream video from cloudfront with jwplayer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, jwplayer

I cannot stream a file from cloudfront with using jwplayer. Here is my code:

```js
jwplayer("container").setup({
    file: "mp4:mediaTest.mp4",
    height: "480",
    provider: "rtmp",
    streamer: "rtmp://s1cp0j2rq4xbq.cloudfront.net:1935/cfx/st",
    width: "853"
});
```

You can find the code at http://stritfun.com/

But when I change

```
file: "mp4:mediaTest.mp4",
```

with:

```
file: "http://s3.amazonaws.com/idastreaming/mediaTest.mp4",
```

streaming succeeded.

What's wrong with file: `mp4:mediaTest.mp4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "streamer/file" setup you are using is used by an older version of JW Player (JW5), but not by the latest version (JW6). We're still going back and forth with Cloudfront to update their docs...

Anyway, setting the RTMP stream with just a single "file" will work for JW6:

> file: "rtmp://s1cp0j2rq4xbq.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:mediaTest.mp4"